# How To Make A Button On php that open a link in a new tab

Tags: php, button

is there any way to make a button in php that open a link in a new tab?
i have solve the problem by open iframes with the links
but now i want to add on the top of the page a button to go back to home page
how can i do that

```html
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="publiadd_publix"; // Mysql username 
$password="1a3g7893fsh"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="publiadd_urlrotator"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="url_rotator"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

     $query = 'SELECT * FROM url_rotator ORDER BY root_name DESC LIMIT 10';
     $result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.<br />Query: ".$query."<br />Error: (".mysql_errno().") ".mysql_error());
// Print Title

print '<center>'."All Rotator In Our Network! ".'</center>';
print '<center>'."---------------------------".'</center>';
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
          $id = $row['id'];
          $root_name = $row['root_name'];
          $root_url1 = $row['root_url1'];
          $root_url2 = $row['root_url2'];
          $root_url3 = $row['root_url3'];
          $root_url4 = $row['root_url4'];
          $root_url5 = $row['root_url5'];
          $root_url6 = $row['root_url6'];
          $root_url7 = $row['root_url7'];
          $root_url8 = $row['root_url8'];
          $root_url9 = $row['root_url9'];
          $root_url10 = $row['root_url10'];
echo '<center>'.$row['id'] . " | " . $row['root_name'] . " | " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url1'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url2'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url3'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url4'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url5'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url6'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url7'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url8'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url9'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo '<center>'.$row['root_url10'] . " * " .'</center>' ;
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url1}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url2}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url3}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url4}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url5}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url6}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url7}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url8}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url9}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
echo  "<iframe src=\"{$root_url10}\" style=\"background: #fff;\" frameborder=\"0\" height=\"450\" scrolling=\"auto\" width=\"100%\"></iframe>";
     }//end while
// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
//<a href="<?php echo $root_url10 ?>"><?php echo $root_url10 ?></a>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
<center><br><br><form>
<input type="button" value="Back" onclick="window.location.href='http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/home.php'" />
</form></center>
</body>
```

Comment: Isn't it possible to style a link like a button and to just use target="_blank"?

Comment: tank you to have replay

Comment: what i meen i want to place this button were is the print instruction

Comment: i want to place it after it

Answer (score 1):

Just replace window.location.href with window.open.

Try this:

```
 <?php
     $host="localhost"; // Host name 
     /* Codes */
      $result = mysql_query($query) or die("<b>A fatal MySQL error occured</b>.<br />Query: ".$query."<br />Error: (".mysql_errno().") ".mysql_error());
    // Print Title
 ?>
 <!-- Place your button below, separated from PHP tag -->
 <input type="button" value="Back"  onclick="window.open('http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/home.php')" />
 <center>'."All Rotator In Our Network! ".'</center>
 <center>'."---------------------------".'</center>

<?php 
 /* While loop and other codes */
?>
```

Comment: tank you for the help i have try but the page is not load

Comment: You mean it's not opening in a new tab? You might wanna retry because I just checked it out and it seems to be working just fine. :)

Comment: the problem is i want this button on the top of the page and on top of page i have php code so how to put this html button on middle of php code? i like to place it after // Print Title

Comment: Tank You This Is work In Perfection tank you all for the great help